# How to browse tags when autochdir is set?

Tags: tags

I like `autochdir` a lot, but it breaks my tag browsing, e.g.:

main.c:

```
int main(){}
```

d/a.c:

```
int main(){}
```

vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
set autochdir
set tagrelative
set tags=tags;
```

tags:

```
main    d/a.c   /^int main() {}$/;"     f
main    main.c  /^int main() {}$/;"     f
```

generated with `ctags -R`.

Now:

```
vim -u vimrc main.c
:tag main
```

Then this works fine and goes to `d/a.c`:

```
:tn
```

However this fails as it searches for `main.c`:

```
:tp
```

and `:ts` shows relative paths.

I suppose the problem is that `:pwd` is `d/`, and the path it looks for is just `main.c` which is not present in `d/`.

Even more confusing to me, if I do:

```
vim -u vimrc d/a.c
```

then everything works, and `:ts` shows absolute paths.

How to solve this? Why isn't `tagrelative` helping?

vim 8.0, Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Don't know why Vim behaves like this, but at least as a workaround you might try running `ctags` as `ctags -R $PWD`, which should put absolute paths into `tags` file.

Comment: @xaizekt thanks! That works as expected. Feel free to add the comment as an answer as it provides a good workaround.

Comment: I now think this behaviour is a bug, would you like report it or should I?

Comment: @xaizek go for it!

Comment: To track progress: reported as [issue #2221](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2221).

Answer (score 5):

#### Workaround

Since the problem happens because of relative paths in `tags` file, it will go away if there are only absolute paths. `ctags` has `--tag-relative` option, which:

> Indicates that the file paths recorded in the tag file should be relative to the directory containing the tag file, rather than relative to the current directory, **unless the files supplied on the command
>   line are specified with absolute paths**. This option must appear before the first file name. The default is yes when running in etags mode (see the -e option), no otherwise.

An easy way of doing it is to run `ctags` like this:

```
ctags -R $PWD
```

#### Cause of the issue

After looking at the source code, I'm pretty sure that this strange behaviour is a bug related to caching of tag search results.

From what I understood Vim uses relative path to `tags` in current directory (can be checked via `:echo tagfiles()`), but absolute path otherwise. For

```
vim -u vimrc main.c
```

`"tags"` path is stored in the cache, but it is impossible to compose full path if all you have is `"tags"` and `"main.c"`. This is why `'tagrelative'` doesn't work, input data required for it to work is missing. For

```
vim -u vimrc d/a.c
```

Vim uses full path (not `"../tags"`) and everything works as expected.